# Dependency injection of UI components via React context

Tags: dependency-injection, reactjs

In React, it's common for libraries, and app-internal utilities, to used context-based dependency injection. Some examples:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const client = useApolloClient(); // Apollo
  const store = useStore(); // React-Redux
  const { me, logout } = useContext(AuthContext); // utilities
  // etc..
}
```

**I wonder, has anybody seen serious (or any for that matter) usage of the same technique for dependency injection of UI components?** Would/could it solve any particular problem out there?

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const { Button, TabBar, Header, NavList } = useContext(UIContext);
  // etc.
}
```

Some thoughts:

- I've once written a hook that returns a component definition (instead of just some jsx), because I wanted to dynamically generate some component dynamically depending on state, but also to be able to render multiple of them.
- In the typical theme use-case, I imagine it would just be a bit of an inversion of control, where instead of "consuming and applying the theme", you would be "letting the theme itself deal with it"

  ```js
  // consuming/applying theme from context
  const { colors } = useTheme();
  return <button style={{ color: colors.primary }}>hello</button>;

  // let the
  const { Button } = useThemedComponents();
  return <Button>hello</Button>;
  ```